# Socket.ReceiveAsync not calling e.Completed event

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, flash

I'm changing some old sync/threaded code to async,
basically im implementing a 'server emulator' for an old flash game,
and trying to make the packet reading async to hopefully speed things up a little.

```
        private List<byte> currentPacket = new List<byte>();
        private byte[] workBuffer = new byte[1028];
        private bool dcLock = false;

        public GameClient(Socket clientSocket)
        {
            ClientSocket = clientSocket;
            RemoteIp = clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

            if (RemoteIp.Contains(":"))
                RemoteIp = RemoteIp.Substring(0, RemoteIp.IndexOf(":"));

            Logger.DebugPrint("Client connected @ " + RemoteIp);

            kickTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(kickTimerTick), null, kickInterval, kickInterval);
            warnTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(warnTimerTick), null, warnInterval, warnInterval);
            minuteTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(minuteTimerTick), null, oneMinute, oneMinute);

            connectedClients.Add(this);

            SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            e.Completed += receivePackets;
            e.SetBuffer(workBuffer, 0, workBuffer.Length);
            ClientSocket.ReceiveAsync(e);
        }

        public static void CreateClient(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            Socket eSocket = e.AcceptSocket;
            e.AcceptSocket = null;
            socket.AcceptAsync(e);

            GameClient client = new GameClient(eSocket);
        }

        private void receivePackets(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {

            // HI1 Packets are terminates by 0x00 so we have to read until we receive that terminator

            if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success && !isDisconnecting)
            {

                int availble = e.BytesTransferred;
                if (availble >= 1)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < availble; i++)
                    {
                        currentPacket.Add(e.Buffer[i]);
                        if (e.Buffer[i] == PacketBuilder.PACKET_TERMINATOR)
                        {
                            parsePackets(currentPacket.ToArray());
                            currentPacket.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                }

                Array.Clear(e.Buffer);
                ClientSocket.ReceiveAsync(e);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Disconnect();
            }

            while (dcLock) { }; // Refuse to shut down until dcLock is cleared. (prevents TOCTOU issues.)


            // Stop Timers
            if (inactivityTimer != null)
                inactivityTimer.Dispose();
            if (warnTimer != null)
                warnTimer.Dispose();
            if (kickTimer != null)
                kickTimer.Dispose();

            // Call OnDisconnect
            connectedClients.Remove(this);
            GameServer.OnDisconnect(this);
            LoggedIn = false;

            // Close Socket
            ClientSocket.Close();
            ClientSocket.Dispose();

            return; 
        }
```

now you see

```
e.Completed += receivePackets;
e.SetBuffer(workBuffer, 0, workBuffer.Length);
ClientSocket.ReceiveAsync(e);
```

for some reason receivePackets is never being called,
if i open up NetCat and connect to 127.0.0.1:12321 and send stuff there it works,
but from in the original flash-based client of the game? nothing happens.
no call to receivePackets ever happens, even if the buffer is only 1 byte.
even after disconnecting the client...

*but it worked in my sync implementation where i just called clientSocket.Receive() in a loop..* so why doesnt it work now in async verison?